# Set variable value from select - syntax error if not in brackets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering why this is not working: (syntax error)

```
declare @pis int = select 7
```

but this works:

```
declare @pis int = (select 7)
```

or this:

```
declare @pis int = 7
```

What is wrong with `select 7` ?

Comment: Design compromise in the parser at a guess, trying to figure out where the select statement ended would be a pain.

Comment: I think without the parentheses SQL server interprets that you are attempting to set the variable to the word SELECT, without quotes, versus the result of your query. i.e.how would it know to throw the correct error if you wanted to set it to the word 'SELECT' versus use this reserved word as a query and just forgot to enclose it in quotes? If your query was incorrect, then which error would it choose? Parentheses just makes this explicit at a guess. Same idea with sub queries... note this only matters when you inline the set and declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version:

```
declare @pis int = (select 7);
```

is using a *subquery* to set the value of `@pis`.  In particular, this is a *scalar* subquery.  A scalar subquery has two important properties:

- It returns exactly 1 column.
- It returns at most one row.

A scalar subquery can be used where a constant value is allowed in a query.  A scalar subquery always has to have its own set of parentheses.

I think that last piece is your confusion.  This version:

```
declare @pis int = select 7;
```

is simply a collection of keywords and strings that the parser doesn't know what to do with.  `select` is not allowed after an `=` sign, according to the SQL grammar.